# Is Musaf Shabbos ok to daven alone at home?

Tags: shabbat, musaf

Is it allowed to daven musaf shabbos at home alone without tzibbur minyan ? Or should it only be davened alone or with minyan at Shul ? Where the korbanos should be offered publicly.

Comment: See Mishna Berachot 4:7 where this is disputed

Comment: The only parts of davening that may be an issue to say alone are: 1) Kedushah in Yotzer Ohr and in Uva Letzion, which both the Alter Rabbe and the Mishnah Berurah rule that it is permitted, (but is better to recite with Trop).  2) the 13 Middos (which according to some is ok when recited with Trop)  3) Hallel on the days when only part of it is recited, but the Alter Rabbe and the Mishnah Berurah both rule that it is permitted  4) when reciting Selichos, not to recite the parts in the end that are in Aramaic

Comment: I've heard Kedusha in Yotzer ohr is a bit more lenient for one to say alone, but Kedusha Desidra is advised to recite with a minyan at shul or atleast around nine other yidden in Shul, for those who missed the public kedusha in amidah, also because it has a slightly higher level than yotzer ohr cus it has the 3rd sanctification "HaShem yimloch l'olam vaed" and is more suitable for a public setting to recite and sanctify HaShem with.